# Exec not working on Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a OrangePI PC board with Raspbian image and default LAMP stack on it. I am trying to run PHP exec function but there is no response.

```
exec("/bin/ls 2>&1", $out);
var_dump($out);
```

returns `array(0) { }`

It works perfectly when I run it manually with cli (`php file.php`), but when I access it via browser it returns empty array.

I have also tried `echo test` and there is no safe_mode directive in config files.
What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it's a permission problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18797512

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try it later. Didn't know there are special permissions for accessing bash.

Comment: It looks like this was not the problem. I checked my passwd file and the user running my server (www-data) had a "/bin/sh" in the end.